# Moving a specific elemnt from block element

Tags: magento2, blocks

How do I move just the Sign In from header.panel to header content?

I have this snippet but is not the desired output

```
 <move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart" as="links"/>
```

Comment: `<move element="header.panel" destination="header.panel.wrapper"/>` try this

Comment: let me know result

Comment: hm I deleted the cache but nothing appears `<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
        <move element="header.panel" destination="header.panel.wrapper"/>`

Comment: `<move element="header.panel" destination="header.container" after="-"/>` try this